# Firebase Select similar data

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in Firebase Technology, How can I retrieve similar data from my table.
1.I would like to retrieve data similar C1.

[image: My Data Structure]

2. I want to show all data that including C1 in child node.

[image: Detail Structure]

Here is my code.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/messages/');
    ref.orderByKey().startAt("C1")
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();

      console.log(value);
    })
    .catch(next);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your effort ?

Comment: Here is my code

var ref = firebase.database().ref('/messages/'); //root reference to your data
        ref.orderBy('C1C3')
        .once('value')
     .then(function(snapshot) {
       var value = snapshot.val();

       console.log(value);
     })
     .catch(next);

Comment: Edit your question . Don't post your attempt on comment section.